# Renaming files like 20141207_190822.jpg to "2014-12-07 19.08.22.jpg" in linux or MacOS X

Tags: linux, macos, filenames

How in Linux or MacOS X to rename a bunch of files with names 20141207_190822.jpg and 20141207_190823.mp4 to this format:

2014-12-07 19.08.22.jpg
and
2014-12-07 19.08.23.mp4

?

I've found many examples how to just add something to the beginning of filename, but here I need to change the mask by inserting symbols in the middle of filenames and replacing _ with space " ".

Thank you

Comment: I'm guessing since this is on stack overflow, that you want a programming solution, but if this is a routine file management problem, Thunar file manager's bulk-rename tool is excellent for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this :

```
$ rename 's@^(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})_(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})@$1-$2-$3 $4.$5.$6@' *
```

[image: warning]
 **There are other tools with the same name which may or may not be able to do this, so be careful.**

If you run the following command :

```
$ file $(readlink -f $(type -p rename))
```

and you have a result like

```
.../rename: Perl script, ASCII text executable
```

then this seems to be the right tool =)

---

If you don't have this command, search your package manager to install it or [do it manually](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/RMBARKER/File-Rename-0.20/rename.PL)

---

Last but not least, this tool was originally written by Larry Wall, the Perl's dad.

Comment: Installed rename:
`brew install rename`
After that the command worked 
`$ rename 's@^(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})_(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})@$1-$2-$3 $4.$5.$6@' *`
Thank you